# TextInputへの値の設定について

Tags: react-native

TextInputにプログラムから値を設定する方法がわかりません

キーボードから入力したい値は、stateに入れることはわかるのですが、stateを変えても反映されることでもないと思います

```
state = {
    userid : null,
}

_changeText = ({ data }) => {
    this.state.userid = data;
    //この処理で、TextInputに設定したい
}

<Button
        onPress={ () => this._changeText("hoge") }>
</Button>
<TextInput
        value={this.state.userid}
/>
```

ボタンを押すと、TextInputに「hoge」を設定するのが目的です

プログラムから設定するケースが、検索でも見つけられず困っております

Comment: 手元で確かめられていないので回答ではなくコメントにさせていただきますが、`this.state.userid = data;`の代わりに`this.setState({userid: data});`としてもだめでしょうか？　一般にReactでは、`this.state`を直接編集するのではなく`this.setState`を使って`state`を変更します。

Comment: うまく行きました。ただしTextInputにキーボードから入力出来なくなりました。キーボードは表示されるのですが、反映されないという感じです。当初の質問とずれますが、どなたか教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: TextInputの内容は`value={this.state.userid}`というように固定されています。ですので、TextInputの変更に合わせてそれを`this.state.userid`に反映させる必要があります。　具体的には、TextInputに `onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({userid: text})}` 属性を追加するとよいのではないかと思います。　TextInputの使い方は[公式ページ（英語ですが）](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input)に書いてありますのでコード等を参考にされるとよいと思います。

Comment: ご提示いただいた方法で出来ました。公式の情報もありがございました。